# C# Circle Pathfinding

Tags: c#, path-finding

Yesterday i detected a strange behaviour in my C# code.
My setup is (not exactly, but compareable with) the following:

The user sees a **grid of checkboxes**, where I assign the checkbox in the middle the coords 0,0.

I wrote a struct for easier comparison between two coords:

```
public struct Coord
{
  public int x, y;

  public static bool operator == (Coord coord1, Coord coord2)
  {
    return coord1.x == coord2.x && coord1.y == coord2.y;
  }

  public static bool operator != (Coord coord1, Coord coord2)
  {
    return coord1.x != coord2.x || coord1.y != coord2.y;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return this.x.GetHashCode() ^ this.y.GetHashCode();
  }

  public override bool  Equals(object obj)
  {
    if (!(obj is Coord))
      return false;

    Coord coord = (Coord)obj;

    if (coord.x == this.x && coord.y == this.y)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

For a checkbox I use a class called Position which inherits from the standart WinForms checkbox:

```
public class Position : CheckBox
{
  public Coord coord;
  public List<Position> nearPositions = new List<Position>();

  public Position(int x, int y)
  {
    this.coord.x = x;
    this.coord.y = y;
  }

  protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.Checked)
      return;

    base.OnClick(e);

    this.checkConnections();
  }

  private void checkConnections()
  {
    foreach (Position position in this.nearPositions)
    {
      Route route = new Route(this, position);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the user can click each checkbox only once.
**The List nearPositions only contains clicked checkboxes near this one**.
Now in the checkConnections() methode I try to find out wether all (or only some) clicked checkboxes can be connected to a circle.
Therefore I create a new object of my class Route for each possibile path.

```
public class Route
{
  private Position startPosition;
  private List<Position> nodes = new List<Position>();

  public Route(Position startPosition, Position nextPosition)
  {
    this.startPosition = startPosition;
    this.nodes.Add(nextPosition);
    this.findConnection();
  }

  public Route(Route route, Position nextPosition)
  {
    this.startPosition = route.startPosition;
    this.nodes = route.nodes;
    this.Add(nextPosition);
    this.findConnection();
  }

  private void findConnection()
  {
    if (this.nodes.Count > 2 && this.nodes[this.nodes.Count - 1].nearPositions.Contains(this.startPosition))
    {
      //HERE THE ROUTE IS A CIRCLE
      return;
    }
    List<Position> nextPositions = this.nodes[this.nodes.Count - 1].nearPositions.FindAll(p => !p.Equals(this.startPosition) && !this.nodes.Contains(p));
    foreach (Position position in nextPositions)
    {
      if (this.nodes[this.nodes.Count - 1].nearPositions.FindAll(p => !p.Equals(this.startPosition) && !this.nodes.Contains(p)).Contains(position)) //TODO strange problem here...bad workaround need to fix
      {
        Route route = new Route(this, position);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Remember that I create an object of Route for every possibity. So if the circle contains many checkboxes there exists a lot of Route objects at the same time. Maybe its important to reproduce my problem.
The Route has always the same startPosition. Its the Position the user clicked.
In the List nodes I save the steps to build the cricle.

Now what I get is the inside the findConnection() methode the List nextPosition sometimes contains Positions which doesn't even exsists inside the this.nodes[this.nodes.Count - 1].nearPositions list. That's why I added the extra condition inside the foreach loop.

My thoughts where that its maybe a bug of the .FindAll() method or a problem with the exitsting of mutiple eoutes at the same time.

So my questions:
 1. Can you reproduce my issue?
 2. Where does it come from?
 3. How can i solve it?

Thank you for you responses!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: You are not doing anything with the Route that you create in findConnection and checkConnections methods. Should you add them to some List or other data structure? I can't see any side effects of these methods.

Comment: @NikolaD-Nick
at the point
//HERE THE ROUTE IS A CIRCLE
I call another function to process the Route but i think it doesn't matter at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
The problem is in the

```
public Route(Route route, Position nextPosition)
{
  this.startPosition = route.startPosition;
  this.nodes = route.nodes;
  this.Add(nextPosition);
  this.findConnection();
}
```

The new route only gets an reference to the nodes of the previous route but it should have its own node list.
So I changed it to

```
public Route(Route route, Position nextPosition)
{
  this.startPosition = route.startPosition;
  this.nodes.AddRange(route.nodes);
  this.Add(nextPosition);
  this.findConnection();
}
```

I should have seen that earlier. I'm sorry!
But anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should try to pinpoint the problem and post shorter code that shows the thing that isn't working for you. It's somewhat time consuming to read through all the details and figure out the algorithm, and most of the details are not relevant.

That said, one suspicious thing you did that I saw was in the way you defined the `Coord` struct. You gave it an equality operator override which correctly compares the members, but in your `Equals` override you do not compare the members.

If your problem was that `FindAll` was not working correctly, and you verified using the debugger that the contents of the lists were correct, then this `Equal` override may be the reason for the problem.

And you should also change your `GetHashCode` override to combine the members' values.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply!  
i already shortened the code a lot but as i cannot point out the exact position of the error, i don't know which piece of code is important or not... better too much than truncating th important parts ;)  


I completely remove the implementation of the overridden .Equals() and .GetHashCode() methods but nothing changed so this isn't the solution.

Comment: Instead of removing the overrides, try implementing them correctly... The `operator==`, the `Equal` override, and `GetHashCode` should all have consistent logic.

Comment: Ok i updated the two methods like I edited the code above. The behaviour didn't change.
The debugger shows that these methods are never called.
In my opinion the problem is not in the struct.